# NDepend to find if control is checked inside the Constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, catel, ndepend

On a WPF project I'm developing with [Catel](https://github.com/Catel/Catel) framework, I'm using IoC pattern to inject services and repositories. I wish to use NDpend to find if all the injected interfaces have the following check applied.
Please consider the following constructor

```
  public ManageInstrumentsViewModel(IMarkToMarketRepository repository, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory,
        IPortfoliosService portfoliosService, IPkInstrumentsService pkInstrumentsService)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;

        this.portfoliosService = portfoliosService;
        this.pkInstrumentsService = pkInstrumentsService;

        Model = new FilterDateRangePortfolioModel {NeedPortfolio = false};
        PortfolioModel = new PortfolioModel();

        LoadMtmInstrumentsCommand = new TaskCommand(OnLoadMtmInstrumentsCommandExecute, (() => CanLoadMtmCurrenciesCommandExecute));
        ModifyValueCommand = new TaskCommand<MtmInstrument>(OnModifyValueCommandExecute, mtmCurrencyResult => IsFunctionReadWrite);
    }
```

This hasn't got the check I need to verify with NDepend.

The corrected one should be

```
 public ManageInstrumentsViewModel(IMarkToMarketRepository repository, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory,
        IPortfoliosService portfoliosService, IPkInstrumentsService pkInstrumentsService)
    {

        Argument.IsNotNull(()=>repository);
        Argument.IsNotNull(()=> viewModelFactory);
        Argument.IsNotNull(()=> portfoliosService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(()=> pkInstrumentsService);

        this.repository = repository;
        this.viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;

        this.portfoliosService = portfoliosService;
        this.pkInstrumentsService = pkInstrumentsService;

        Model = new FilterDateRangePortfolioModel {NeedPortfolio = false};
        PortfolioModel = new PortfolioModel();

        LoadMtmInstrumentsCommand = new TaskCommand(OnLoadMtmInstrumentsCommandExecute, (() => CanLoadMtmCurrenciesCommandExecute));
        ModifyValueCommand = new TaskCommand<MtmInstrument>(OnModifyValueCommandExecute, mtmCurrencyResult => IsFunctionReadWrite);
    }
```

The Argument.IsNotNull can be found [here](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.Shared/Argument.cs)

Comment: With NDepend you can check if a ctor accepting as argument an IMarkToMarketRepository (and/or other interfaces) is calling the method Argument.IsNotNull() but you cannot check if Argument.IsNotNull() is called for all passed interfaces. Would this help you?

Comment: no I would have to check it for each passed interface

Comment: it is not possible for now

Comment: can it be added to feature request?

Comment: Sure, please add it in the User Voice https://ndepend.uservoice.com/